# WCF: how to create a large number of classes in the contract?

Tags: wcf, serialization

Well, I am creating a WCF service, that have a large number of classes to communicate with the client, and this classes have also many properties.

Mainly, this classes are the POCO classes that is created with the code generator from the edmx, and I have the .tt file.

To can use this classes and properties, I have to use the DataContract and *DataMember*, so in each classes I have to set the *DataContract* and in each property of the each class the *DataMemeber*. So this a big work, so if I need to do some modify to the data base, I must generate again the tt file and then repeat the work.

Is there any way to do this automatically? I am using .NET 4.0 and EF 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of the .tt file being added to your project is so that you can modify the template to suit your needs. All you need to do is change the template so that it adds `[DataContract]` to the entity class definition and `[DataMember]` to the entity property definitions.

From there, any time the DB is changed you simple use the "Update model from database" feature and your entities will automatically have their code regenerated using the existing template.

All that said, I'm going to recommend you *do not* expose your DB entities, POCO or not, directly from your service layer. You should really be designing with domain separation and using messaging and [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) type patterns at the service level. Then you just have some simple mapping methods that translate the data between those messages/commands to your entities.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Entity Framework Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673932.aspx) with WCF data services, might be it can help you.